# Missing value imputation

Tags: missing-data, imputation

If in a dataset we have missing values in both categorical and continuous variables, how can I deal with them by replacing with mode for the categorical variable and mean for the continuous variable?

Comment: How is this data stored? Can you provide any sample data?

Answer (score 0):

When the missing data are missing at random, you could impute the missing values using multiple imputation.

For more information about multiple imputation, I would recommend the book Applied Missing Data by C.K. Enders (2010). It also has a great [companion website](http://www.appliedmissingdata.com/multilevel-imputation.html).

For multiple imputation in `R` you could use the `mice` package. Here is the [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) to the package on `CRAN`, the [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf) to the documentation, and the [link](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03/v45i03.pdf) to the article in the *Journal of Statistical Software*.

There are other packages for multiple imputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use either fillna() or interpolate()

For more details about these two please refer my answer to this question in StackOverflow. link is: [Missing values in Time Series in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308530/missing-values-in-time-series-in-python/54494569#54494569)